# How to display error message for field validation in SugarCRM?

Tags: sugarcrm, suitecrm

Using SugarCRM v6.5.26. I need to display an inline error message instead of "alert" for validation of the last name.

JavaScript file path (sample code is given):

*/custom/modules/Contacts/js/editview.js*

```
$('input#last_name').on('change', function () {
      var node = $(this);
      node.val(node.val().replace(/[^a-z]/g, ''));
      alert("Please enter only charcter");
});
```

Again, I don't want to show an alert, only inline message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is something related to javsacrip/jquery error handling and you can find many logics on google as well.

Try following code:

```
$('input#last_name').on('change', function () {      
    handleLastNameValidation();
    return false;
});

 var clickAttr = $("#SAVE_HEADER").attr("onclick"); 
 $("#SAVE_HEADER").attr("onclick","return handleLastNameValidation(); "+clickAttr);


function handleLastNameValidation(){

    clear_all_errors();

    var node = $('input#last_name');
        current_val = node.val();
        trimmed_val = node.val().replace(/[^a-z]/g, '');

    if( current_val != trimmed_val || trimmed_val =='')
    {
        add_error_style('EditView', 'last_name', 'Please enter correct value for last name',true);
        return false;
    }
    else 
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: hi star is working but there some issue when i am click save button then record have been created. i want to not create have record

Comment: hey star not worked ur answer. record should not be saved

Comment: last name is required field?

Comment: you can see that i am setting save button as disabled, i.e. $("#SAVE").attr("disabled","disabled"); . See if your save button ID is different then replace it accordingly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158846/discussion-between-divyesh-sigmate-and-star).